# How do I measure elapsed time inside Cats IO effect?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, scala-cats, cats-effect

I'd like to measure elapsed time inside IO container. It's relatively easy to do with plain calls or futures (e.g. something like the code below)

```
class MonitoringComponentSpec extends FunSuite with Matchers with ScalaFutures {

  import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

  def meter[T](future: Future[T]): Future[T] = {
    val start = System.currentTimeMillis()
    future.onComplete(_ => println(s"Elapsed ${System.currentTimeMillis() - start}ms"))
    future
  }

  def call(): Future[String] = Future {
    Thread.sleep(500)
    "hello"
  }

  test("metered call") {
    whenReady(meter(call()), timeout(Span(550, Milliseconds))) { s =>
      s should be("hello")
    }
  }
}
```

But not sure how to wrap IO call

```
  def io_meter[T](effect: IO[T]): IO[T] = {
    val start = System.currentTimeMillis()
    ???
  }

  def io_call(): IO[String] = IO.pure {
    Thread.sleep(500)
    "hello"
  }

  test("metered io call") {
    whenReady(meter(call()), timeout(Span(550, Milliseconds))) { s =>
      s should be("hello")
    }
  }
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 8):

Cats-effect has a [Clock](https://typelevel.org/cats-effect/datatypes/clock.html) implementation that allows pure time measurement as well as injecting your own implementations for testing when you just want to simulate the passing of time. The example from their documentation is:

```scala
def measure[F[_], A](fa: F[A])
  (implicit F: Sync[F], clock: Clock[F]): F[(A, Long)] = {

  for {
    start  <- clock.monotonic(MILLISECONDS)
    result <- fa
    finish <- clock.monotonic(MILLISECONDS)
  } yield (result, finish - start)
}
```

Comment: This is not quite equivalent to the OP's `Future` implementation though as `Future.onComplete` would time failure cases

Answer (score 2):

In cats effect 3, you can use `.timed`. Like,

```scala
import cats.effect.IO
import cats.effect.unsafe.implicits.global
import cats.implicits._
import scala.concurrent.duration._

val twoSecondsLater = IO.sleep(2.seconds) *> IO.println("Hi")

val elapsedTime = twoSecondsLater.timed.map(_._1)
elapsedTime.unsafeRunSync()

// would give something like this. 
Hi
res0: FiniteDuration = 2006997667 nanoseconds
```